# How do I view the execution time of my program?

Tags: linux, performance, time, terminal

I want to find just how long my program takes to run from start to finish in order to compare it with a past version.

How would I go about finding the time it takes for both of these versions? I'm running ubuntu 12.04LTS

Comment: Hint: `man time`.

Comment: You might want to use some appropriate profiling tool like [gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html) for this. In addition to the already mentioned `time` command this enables you to see **where** you gained performance optimization in your code or not.

Comment: How this question is related to C++?

Comment: @MM. The code was written in C++. I had thought I might need to write a time function originally so that tag would be useful. Tag has been removed

Comment: @Gmercer015: Reminding I wasn't the down-voter. The suggested methods in answers measure the whole time of load/startup and termination of the application by OS. If you need actual time, you should put some code in your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`time`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?time) command:

```
time yourprogram
```

By default it will output something similar to this:

```
real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
```

`real` means the total time your program runs. `user` means the time your program spent in user land code and `sys` is the time your program spent in kernel calls.

Comment: that's some cool stuff, definitely answered my question there. Thanks!

Comment: For extended functionality, use `/usr/bin/time` explicitly to override the built-in time function in shells such as `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Run `time myprogram`
The time command will display all the details you need to know.
Example:

```
rh63-build(greg)~>time ls >/dev/null

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Here is more about the `time` command: http://linux.die.net/man/1/time

Answer (score 1):

Linux comes with the 'time' program.

```
$time ./myapp

real 0m0.002s
user 0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```